# How to do a left (or right) exclude join in R?

Tags: sql, r, join, left-join

What is the R equivalent of this?

```
SELECT <select_list> 
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.Key IS NULL
```

See https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/visual-representation-of-sql-joins - 'Left excluding JOIN'

I have two columns of data:

```
A
Amsterdam
Copenhagen
LA
Lisbon
London 
Madrid
New York
Paris
Rome
Stockholm
```

and

```
B
Amsterdam
Buenos Aires  
Copenhagen
LA
London 
Sydney
Tokyo
```

How do I return the lists:

```
In A ONLY
Lisbon
Madrid
New York
Paris
Rome
Stockholm
```

and

```
In B ONLY
Buenos Aires
Sydney
Tokyo
```

in R?

I've been trying and searching for solutions using the `merge()` function for about three hours.

Similarly, is there a way to do a left join in R that returns *both* columns?

For example, if I call:

```
A <- data.frame(A = c("Amsterdam",
                      "Copenhagen",
                      "LA",
                      "Lisbon",
                      "London", 
                      "Madrid",
                      "New York",
                      "Paris",
                      "Rome",
                      "Stockholm"))

B <- data.frame(B = c("Amsterdam",
                      "Buenos Aires",
                      "Copenhagen",
                      "LA",
                      "London", 
                      "Sydney",
                      "Tokyo"))

merge(A, B, by.x = "A", by.y = "B", all.x = T)
```

I get

```
            A
1   Amsterdam
2  Copenhagen
3          LA
4      Lisbon
5      London
6      Madrid
7    New York
8       Paris
9        Rome
10  Stockholm
```

But I want

```
            A   B
1   Amsterdam   Amsterdam
2  Copenhagen   Copenhagen
3          LA   LA
4      Lisbon   NULL
5      London   London 
6      Madrid   NULL
7    New York   NULL
8       Paris   NULL
9        Rome   NULL
10  Stockholm   NULL
```

Comment: Create a column of `A` and you do the `merge` in `R` i.e. `merge(A, transform(B, A = B), all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: That link is trash.

Answer (score 2):

```
## A only
setdiff(A,B)
[1] "Lisbon"    "Madrid"    "New York"  "Paris"     "Rome"      "Stockholm"

## B only
setdiff(B,A)
[1] "Buenos Aires" "Sydney"       "Tokyo"
```

Answer (score 1):

We create a column of 'A' in 'B' and then do the `merge`

```
merge(A, transform(B, A = B), all.x = TRUE)
#            A          B
#1   Amsterdam  Amsterdam
#2  Copenhagen Copenhagen
#3          LA         LA
#4      Lisbon       <NA>
#5      London     London
#6      Madrid       <NA>
#7    New York       <NA>
#8       Paris       <NA>
#9        Rome       <NA>
#10  Stockholm       <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(A, B = "NULL", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
isinB <- df$A %in% B$B
df[isinB, "B"] <- as.character(df[isinB, "A"])


print(df)
            A          B
1   Amsterdam  Amsterdam
2  Copenhagen Copenhagen
3          LA         LA
4      Lisbon       NULL
5      London     London
6      Madrid       NULL
7    New York       NULL
8       Paris       NULL
9        Rome       NULL
10  Stockholm       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

For excluding the city mentioned in `b` from `a`. `a` is left table and `b` is right table. the below is similar to left excluding join. `Left excluding join = Left join - inner join`.

```
a <- data.frame(a);
colnames(a) <- city;

b <- data.frame(b);
colnames(b) <- city;
b$indicator <- c("indicator");

a_excl_b <- merge(x = a, y = b, all = FALSE, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE);
a_excl_b <- subset(a_excl_b, is.na(indicator));
a_excl_b <- data.frame(a_excl_b$city);
colnames(a_excl_b ) <- c("city");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, my first comment on here so I dont know how to correctly format answer to look like R yet**

Use anti_join(A,B) and the anti_join(B,A). The results:

> anti_join(A,B) 
> Joining, by = "Y" 
> Y 
> 1    Lisbon 
> 2    Madrid 
> 3  New York 
> 4     Paris 
> 5      Rome 
> 6 Stockholm
>
> anti_join(B,A) 
> Joining, by = "Y" 
> Y 
> 1 Buenos Aires 
> 2       Sydney 
> 3        Tokyo

And to merge them two by matches:

> aux<- inner_join(A,B) 
> aux2<- anti_join(B,A) 
> i<-1:nrow(A) 
> c<-ifelse(A$Y[i] %in% aux$Y, A$Y[i],"NA") 
> A<-cbind(A,c) 
> A<-rbind(A,data.frame(Y=rep("NA",nrow(anti_join(B,A))),c=aux2$Y)) 
> A 
> Y           c 
> 1   Amsterdam           Amsterdam 
> 2  Copenhagen           Copenhagen 
> 3          LA           LA 
> 4      Lisbon           NA 
> 5      London       London 
> 6      Madrid           NA 
> 7    New York           NA 
> 8       Paris           NA 
> 9        Rome           NA 
> 10  Stockholm           NA 
> 11         NA Buenos Aires 
> 12         NA       Sydney 
> 13         NA        Tokyo